# Implement Percentage (%) button in Calculator

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement, calculator, percentage

I am new to SO & Android Programming. I have Calculator code in which I want to implement Percent (%) button function like how it is used in actual (casio,citizen etc) calculators.
e.g enter **50** then press **+(add)** enter **5** then press **%** answer equals **52.5**. Likewise the behavior of % button changes for MULTIPLY, MINUS or SUBTRACT & DIVIDE.
e.g enter **50** then press **-(subtract)** enter **5** then press **%** answer equals **47.5**.
Basically on add function (num1 = 50, num2 = 5) num1 + num2 when I press % button num2*0.01*num1+num1 this calculation takes place.

Here is my code for cuaculating percent:

```
 if (operateString.equals(ADD)) {
        num1 = num2 + num1;
        if
        ((operateString.equals(ADD)) && num2 !=0 
        && operateString.equals(PERCENTAGE)){
            numPer = num2*0.01*num1+num1;
            num1 = numPer +num1;
            }
```

I don't know how to carry on the num1 & num2 values to nested if statement because is showing only the addition successfully. when I press percent button that also shows addition result only i.e.55. I Also don't understand how 'operateString' will behave in nested if statement. & I also don't know whether nested if statement is right choice here.

Here is my full class code:

```
public class Calculator{

private double num1;
private double num2;
private double numPer;
private String operateString;


public static final String ADD = "+";
public static final String SUBTRACT = "-";
public static final String MULTIPLY = "*";
public static final String PERCENTAGE = "%";
public static final String DIVIDE = "/";

public static final String DEL = "<-Del";
public static final String CLEAR = "AC" ;

public static final String SQUAREROOT = "√";
public static final String SQUARED = "x²";
public static final String INVERT = "1/x";
public static final String TOGGLESIGN = "+/-";


public CalcProcess() {
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    numPer = 0;
    operateString = "";
    }


public void setnum1(double num) {
    num1 = num;
}

public double getResult() {
    return num1;
}

public String toString() {
    return Double.toString(num1);
}

protected double performCalculation(String operator) {
    if (operator.equals(CLEAR)) {
        num1 = 0;
        operateString = "";
        num2 = 0;

    } else if (operator.equals(SQUAREROOT)) {
        num1 = Math.sqrt(num1);

    } else if (operator.equals(SQUARED)) {
        num1 = num1 * num1;

    } else if (operator.equals(INVERT)) {
        if (num1 != 0) {
            num1 = 1 / num1;
        }
    } else if (operator.equals(TOGGLESIGN)) {
        num1 = -num1;

    } else {
        performnextOperation();
        operateString = operator;
        num2 = num1;

    }

    return num1;
}

protected double performnextOperation() {


    if (operateString.equals(ADD)) {
        num1 = num2 + num1;
        if
        ((operateString.equals(ADD)) && num2 !=0 
        && operateString.equals(PERCENTAGE)){
            numPer = num2*0.01*num1+num1;
            num1 = numPer +num1;
            }
```

Just like ADD I have done the same percent operation for DIV, SUB, MULTIPLY but results are only of main function i.e addition, subtraction, multiplication & division...
I am only stuck with the percentage button.. rest all calculations are working absolutely fine.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated as after a lot of search & reseach no forum has this question & this my First question in SO... fingers crossed ... expecting a quick solution.. :)

Comment: your else part is write in elseif... i think so...

Comment: @NAP changing to else if not working... I believe I need to make an entire new function to implement percentage button.

Comment: can anyone help me with percentage implementation..????

Comment: @Vishwakarma I have same issue. Have you got any solutions?